# How can I load image without local server?

Tags: javascript, typescript, image, http, localhost

How can I load image without local server?

local server is a old and big problem for me. When I'm using es6 module, I always need a local server for 'http' format, I solve this by use singlefile compile in typescript. But what about Image? When I'm loading image:

```
const img = new Image();
img.src = "./../blah";
```

Chrome / Safari start complain:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: directory/directory/image
```

It seems like all the browser has same problem.

As I know, Typescript do not have any solutions for this problem.

So problem is, how can load image without localhost server? What should I do?

ps: the reason I don't want to use local server is I want to give my web game to my friend, and all of them said they never touch any programming languages, but local server need languages like python. I just want them to run program in their browser, I can't teach them to install language, and I don't have money to create a server.

Comment: Maybe base64, but if your image is large that isn't a good way.

Comment: _"local server is a old and big problem for me"_... what does this mean? There are so many simple options for running a static HTTP server... [VSCode Live Server extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer), [Caddy (Go)](https://caddyserver.com/), [serve (npm)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve)

Comment: @Phil Please read the last sentence of this question

Comment: @Phil last sentence is: the reason I don't want to use local server is I want to give my web game to my friend, and all of them said they never touch any programming languages, but local server need languages like python. I just want them to run program in their browser, I can't teach them to install language, and I don't have money to create a server.

Comment: There are many free hosting options available too. [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/pricing/) and [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) come to mind

Comment: I think use folder path for image is fine. It will work if all your resource (html, js and img) are in local because it will not cause the Cross-Origin error. You can show more details of your project structure.

Comment: Wouln't just opening your `index.html` in the browser work when all image paths are relative to your local files? Please share an actual example of an image that fails to load.

Answer (score -1):

Where are you getting the image from?
If its static you can upload the image file to the same directory as the website, and then assign the image file path to the src property.

If you have the image data you can use
`img.src = URL.createObjectURL(imageData)` to create a URL representing the object.

Comment: I tried, but doesn't work. The browser doesn't throw an error, but cannot load anything, Image is just empty, when I switch back to my local server url, it works normally.

Comment: Can you upload the image to the directory of the website?